# Right syntax of asp MenuItem NavigateUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net

In code behind:

```
MenuItem.NavigateUrl = string.Format("~/LecturerProfile.aspx?user={0}", id);
```

Now I want to Navigate to another page in aspx page instead of in code behind.

Just like:

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="./LecturerProfile.aspx?user={0},id" Text=" Lectureprofile"/>// it seems to be wrong???
```

I dont know the right syntax of MenuItem NavigateUrl, Help!!!

Comment: Where does the `id` value come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:menuitem navigateurl="<%= string.Format("~/LecturerProfile.aspx?user={0}", id) %>"
              text="Lectureprofile"
              tooltip="Lectureprofile">
```

check this  [MenuItem.NavigateUrl Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitem.navigateurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)